# Magnific Popup - Browser scrolls on the top on image click

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup plugin for displaying image in lightbox.When I click on the image  in Chrome, the browser scrolls on the top, after that the menu is not clickable.

```
$('.img-item').magnificPopup({ 
    type: 'image',
    gallery:{
        enabled:true
    }   
});
```

Comment: Do you have anything else to show as code? HTML perhaps...

Comment: make sure your plug-in is not adding anchor tag with href="#"

Comment: Without more information, you are wasting your bounty. Please post an example of the page HTML and a complete list of the plugins you are using (including versions). Ideally put it all in a JSFiddle :)

Comment: The bounty wasn't his...

Comment: Did you solve it ?, after some 2 hours of CSS, JavaScript, I found a weird solution... here it is:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28749311/2615737

Answer (score 13):

Alright folks, I guess I found the solution.

I trimmed off my full script yet `fixedContentPos: false`, adding `noscroll` to body element on "open" and remove it on "close" is important :

```js
$('.open-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  closeOnBgClick: true,
  fixedContentPos: false,
  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      jQuery('body').addClass('noscroll');
    },
    close: function() {
      jQuery('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, create a CSS rule for noscroll as :

```css
body.noscroll {
  overflow-y: hidden!important;
}
```

`fixedContentPos:false` prevents using fixed position for body and keeps the scrollbar on the same position. However, it doesn't prevent scroll and user is still able to scroll up / down. Using `overlow-y:hidden` hides scrollbar and disables mousewheel.

Comment: Def the best solution. Just doing `fixedContentPos: false` meant the user could scroll, so that's no good. This solution worked like a charm!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I like this solution. Only problem is, when the content of the popup is higher than the popup itself, there is no way to scroll anymore. I fixed it by adding "overflow-y: auto" to .mfp-container.

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked for my situation

Answer (score 7):

Magnific has an option `fixedContentPos`. This is set to 'auto' by default, causing it to fix content to the top. Setting `fixedContentPos: false` should force magnific to use the absolute position based on current scroll.

Comment: didn't work, neither 'auto', true, false. Also, tried with the fixedBgPos and alignTop properties, but no luck., here is how I did it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28749311/2615737

Answer (score 4):

For me it was the problem with `delegate:'a'` option. Everywhere it was set, I need to add `fixedContentPos: false` and this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

> You need use: preventDefault()

JavaScript:

```
function attach_magnific_popup(e){
e.preventDefault();
jQuery('a.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        //fixedContentPos: true,
        //fixedBgPos: true
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#pop-up-content"  class="open-popup-link" onclick="attach_magnific_popup(event);">Click here...!</a>
```

Comment: This did it for me. Placeholder href="#" was causing a jump to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's a JS error somewhere or your image is wrapped into an `<a href=""></a>` tag and it interferes with default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a weird thing. Here is how I fix it:

1. I removed the `.magnificPopup({` code from the `onReady`, and instead move it to a function.
2. Then I added the an *onlick* event to the element which triggers the popup.

I don't know why, but that worked.

---

Here is the code:

JavaScript

```
function attach_magnific_popup(){
jQuery('a.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        //fixedContentPos: true,
        //fixedBgPos: true
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#pop-up-content"  class="open-popup-link" onclick="attach_magnific_popup();">Click here...!</a>


<div id="pop-up-content" class="white-popup mfp-hide" >
....Pop up content...
</div>
```

---

**Note**: I did tried with *fixedBgPos, fixedContentPos, alignTop*  properties, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like moving the magnificPopup code from `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()` did it for me. Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    closeBtnInside: true,
    fixedContentPos: false,
    midClick: true
  });
});
```